# Probability - Solving for $P(C)$ given $P( C \bigcap ( A \bigcup B ) )$ and $P( A \bigcup B )$

Tags: probability

I'm working through my probability textbook and came across a question that I don't fully understand.

Given the sample space $S = A \bigcup B \bigcup C$

$$P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$P(B) = \frac{2}{3}$$
$$P(A \bigcup B) = \frac{5}{6}$$
$$P(C \bigcap (A \bigcup B)) = \frac{5}{12}$$

What is $P(C)?$

My solution is:

$$P(C \bigcap (A \bigcup B)) = P(C) * P(A \bigcup B)$$

$$P(C) = \frac{P(C \bigcap (A \bigcup B))}{P(A \bigcup B)}$$

Which yields $$P(C) = \frac{1}{2}$$

The answer in the textbook says $P(C) = \frac{7}{12}$

I'm obviously missing something and was hoping someone could explain where my logic breaks down.

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion is only valid if $C$ and $A \cup B$ are independent.

In this problem, $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are irrelevant.  Think of the entire sample space $S$ as $D \cup C$, where $D = A \cup B$.  We then have

$$
P(D) = \frac56
$$

$$
P(C \cap D) = \frac{5}{12}
$$

The key is to observe that $P(C \cup D) = 1$, because $S = C \cup D$ is the entire sample space; it *has* to have probability one.  We can now approach this in one of (at least) two ways.  One is to use the identity

$$
P(C) + P(D) = P(C \cup D) + P(C \cap D)
$$

which yields

$$
P(C) + \frac56 = 1 + \frac{5}{12}
$$

whereupon

$$
P(C) = \frac{7}{12}
$$

---

Another way is to recognize that whenever $D$ doesn't hold—which is $\frac16$ of the time—$C$ must hold.  Therefore, $P(C)$ must be at least $1-\frac56 = \frac16$.  Whatever $P(C)$ is in excess of that quantity must be the probability that $C$ and $D$ both hold at the same time.  We are told this probability is $\frac{5}{12}$.  Therefore,

$$
P(C) = \frac16 + \frac{5}{12} = \frac{7}{12}
$$

In essence, these two approaches are equivalent, but from a pedagogical perspective, sometimes one is easier to see than the other.